# How do I deploy an Android app with both Native and Meteor code?

Tags: android, meteor, google-play, apk

I'm developing an app where the main body of the application is built in Meteor, while some of it uses services that are only available through native development. Once I'm close to deploying this on Google Play I will need to wrap up both of these sub-apps together.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

I have read how to deploy meteor apps here - https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html

I also know that  Google allows multiple APK support - https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html
But this is downloading different single apks for different configurations. Whereas I would like to combine both the meteor release and the native android release to work together.

Thank you.

Comment: did you look at Cordova at all?

Answer (score 1):

Remember first that Meteor uses [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) internally to wrap the (Meteor) Web App into a *Hybrid* App (i.e. a Native App that consists mainly of a WebView and a local server that serves your Web App directly from the mobile device).

You have plenty Meteor and Cordova tutorials and resources that explain how to build the Hybrid App for Android (and iOS), for example:

- https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html

Then, remember that once the Web App is packaged as a Hybrid App, it may access *more* native functionalities than an actual Web App accessed through a mobile browser online, thanks to Cordova *plugins* that expose native functionalities through a JavaScript API.

If the services you need are already available through a [Cordova plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/), then you are good to go, simply add it to your Meteor project and you can use the corresponding JS API in your code (possibly wrapping it with [`Meteor.isCordova`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-isCordova) check to make sure your Web App does not crash trying to access an API that will not be available while debugging on a browser).

Your Cordova plugin may even be wrapped as a Meteor Atmosphere package. The syntax to add a Meteor package or a Cordova plugin is slightly different.

If they are not available yet, then you will have to [build your own Cordova plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html). You can then specify a local path when adding it into your Meteor project.